# The PHP file is not displayed in the html email as a message

Tags: php, html

dgkkdk

```
<?php

try{
        $to = "info@info.co.za";
        $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= '
<?php
include_once "database.php";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,upper(make) FROM makes order by upper(make)");
?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Delete employee data</title>
<style>
      tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
      background-color:#ccc;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <?php
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 300px; text-align: center;"><?php echo $row["upper(make)"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>';
        $response = mail($to, 'Query from website', $message,implode("\r\n",$headers));
      print_r($response); 
    } catch(Exception $e){
        print_r($e);
    }
?>
```

The code/page in the $message  is displayed fine when run by itself.

However, when trying to incorporate it into a html email, no data is displayed.

Are you able to run a PHP in the $message?

Please assist.

Comment: 1) You're already in a PHP block, adding more PHP tags will break it... except 2) you have it inside of a single-quoted string, so no variables are going to be interpolated inside. You're already concatenating a string, build it up properly instead of trying to one-line it.

Comment: `Are you able to run a PHP in the $message?`...no, and why would you want to? You're already in a php program, so just get that program to create the content you want for the email, put that into $message, and then send it

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to embed PHP code within a string within... PHP code.  Why?  You may be over-thinking it.

It *looks like* you just want to concatenate strings.  For example:

```
// query the DB
include_once "database.php";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,upper(make) FROM makes order by upper(make)");

// create the start of the HTML
$message .= '
  <html>
  <!--- etc. --->
  <table>';

// append each row to the HTML
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $message .= '<tr><td style="width: 300px; text-align: center;">';
    $message .= $row["upper(make)"];
    $message .= '</td></tr>';
    $i++;
}

// append the end of the HTML
$message .= '</table></body></html>';
```

That is... The receipient's *email client* isn't going to be executing your PHP code.  What you have here is PHP code that your server is executing.  You would use that code to produce the output you want, not to produce other code which someone else would execute to produce the output you want.